# Rails: How do I validate against this code that I put into the lib/ directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Having a bit of difficulty finding out the proper way to mix in code that I put into the lib/ directory for Rails 2.3.5.

I have several models that require phone validation. I had at least three models that used the same code, so I wanted to keep things DRY and moved it out to the lib/ directory. I used to have code like this in each model:

```
validate :phone_is_valid
```

Then I'd have a phone_is_valid method in the model:

```
protected
def phone_is_valid
  # process a bunch of logic
  errors.add_to_base("invalid phone") if validation failed
end
```

I moved this code out into lib/phones/ and in lib/phones I have lib/phones/phone_validation.rb, and in there I copy pasted the phone_is_valid method.

My question is, how do I mix this into all of my models now? And does my validate :phone_is_valid method remain the same or does that change? I want to make sure that the errors.add_to_base method continues to function as it did before while keeping everything DRY. obviously the following won't work:

```
validate :Phones::PhoneValidation::phone_is_valid(number)
```

I also created another file in lib/phones/ called lib/phones/phone_normalize.rb. Again, many models need the value input by the user to be normalized. Meaning turn (555) 222-1212 to 5552221212 or something similar. Can I invoke that simply by invoking Phones::Phone_Normalize::normalize_method(number)?

I suppose I'm confused on the following:

- How to use the lib directory for validation of multiple models that need access to a particular validation method
- How to use the lib directory for commonly shared methods that return values

Comment: I working on a project that needs to validate phone numbers. I don't know if you would find this useful, but I put phone numbers (and their possible extensions) into their OWN model. A cool thing that you can do with this is that you can search phone numbers to find what type of X, Y, or Z are associated it with it. Also I have a before_save method that strips all of the parens, hyphens etc before saving it so they are easily searchable and then you can format the phonenumber in the view very easily that they are uniform. Hope those ideas were useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of metaprogramming magick?

```
module Phones

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def validate_phone(*attr_names)
      #setup the config array eg. configuration = atrr.extract_options!
      validates_each(attr_names, configuration) do |record, attr_name, value|
          record.errors.add(attr_name, configuration[:message]) unless #validation
       end
       #setup the phone normalization
       unless configuration[:normalize]
         before_save do
           # normalization code here
         end
       end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Phones
```

Then in your model:

```
validate_phone :main_phone, :cellphone, :message => "not a valid telephone number"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Phones::PhoneValidation
  validate_phone_is_valid
end
```

If you want to use that for many model then you might monkey patch you validations straight into ActiveRecord:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Validations
    module ClassMethods
      def validates_photo(*attr_names)
        # ....
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be validate :phone_is_valid? Also, what if the column I'm validating has different names in the different models. That means I'd need to be able to pass it to the validation method as an argument. I prefer not baking it directly into ActiveRecord.

Comment: `validate :phone_is_valid?` would call the method `phone_is_valid?` during the validation process, of course possible but it's outside the naming convention for validations.

And for the different attribute names I've put `*attr_names` into my second example of code.